# bootstrap (4) How to amend custom select arrow to change colour

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to amend the arrow used in Boostraps `custom-select` css class.  Currently it's black and would prefer to change this to grey, is there an easy way to do this?
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#select-menu

Comment: The arrows in a Bootstrap 4 custom select are part of a `data:` background image in the `.custom-select` class, so you cannot change the color directly. You would have to remove / replace that background.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The arrows are SVG being used as the background image. You just need to override it with your own CSS by specifying the fill color (the important part below being what you enter in `fill='something'`).

For example:

```
.custom-select {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 4 5'%3E%3Cpath fill='red' d='M2 0L0 2h4zm0 5L0 3h4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E")
}
```

**[Example](https://codeply.com/p/4xExz0uaGY)**

Comment: For fill you can use rgb as, hexs does not work fill='rgb(0,162,221)'

Answer (score 1):

to change black to white use as below and change background color #272a3d as your needs

```
.custom-select {
  background: #272a3d url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 4 5'%3e%3cpath fill='white' d='M2 0L0 2h4zm0 5L0 3h4z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") no-repeat right .75rem center/8px 10px !important;
}
```